# dotCMS not indexing URL mapped content

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, dotcms

I am running dotCMS 21.06.14, and having a problem with the Elasticsearch-based "Site Search" feature. Specifically, URL Mapped content (from content types with dynamically generated detail pages) is not being saved to the ES index.

According to the dotCMS docs (e.g., "https://www.dotcms.com/docs/latest/site-search"), "The Site Search indexes all Pages, Files and *URL Mapped content* which match the specified locations for the Site Search indexing job"

As far as I can tell, I have everything set up correctly.  The content types I am trying to index have values in their "Detail Page" and "URL Pattern" fields, and I know they are correct, because the content renders correctly on the front-end of the website.

But no matter how I've configured the indexing job, the URL mapped content is never indexed. After creating and populating the index, running a query for content from the detail pages will never return hits from the URL mapped detail pages.

- I am not excluding the detail pages from the indexing job.
- There is nothing hiding the URL mapped content from the indexer. That is, I'm not using the technique described at "https://www.dotcms.com/docs/latest/site-search#UserAgent".
- The detail pages are visible to any anonymous user.
- Static pages from the site get indexed just fine - just not the URL mapped content.
- I have three separate Content Types with dynamically generated detail pages, and none of those pages get indexed.

I don't know what else to try. Does anyone have any ideas?